# Why does printf fail to print out NSObject within a run loop?

Tags: objective-c

I'm doing a simple exercise to look at the heap and stack using Objective-C.

I create an NSNumber object in main - I'm assuming that this points to the heap, right? When I try to run `printf` on the object, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

- NSLog works fine - from my understanding, NSLog is printf but extended.
- I can run a printf on an NSString

In the past I've run printf on objects and it wasn't a problem. Did something change or am I missing something obvious?

When I run the debugger and print out the object, I get the result: isa

```
        Printing description of lifeAnswerObject:
        (NSNumber) NSNumber = {
            NSValue = {
                NSObject = {
                    isa = <read memory from 0x966d0398ef3e399b failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>

                }
            }
        }
```

What does this mean? Even though the NSNumber is wrapped in the autoreleasepool it shouldn't be released at this point.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        NSNumber *lifeAnswerObject = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 42];
        NSString *helloWorld = @"Hello out there world";
        NSLog(@"%@ in the heap", lifeAnswerObject);
        // EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
        printf("%s", helloWorld); // survives
        printf("%s", lifeAnswerObject);
        int lifeAnswer = 42;

        printf("%d : in the stack", lifeAnswer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: debugger]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with tagged pointers.

You can’t use `%s` to print an object type ever.   That *it survived* is merely coincidental;   The address of the object happened to not have data that caused it to crash.

Look at the output of the `printf()` of the string.  It is garbage.

If you want to use `printf()`, you need to supply a `char*` buffer.